# Variable assignment exit status

Tags: shell, variable, exit, set

Normally, if has an exit status not zero, execution will continue:

```
false
echo 'this will show'
```

If you use `set -e`, the shell immediately shall exit:

```
set -e
false
echo 'this will not show'
```

I am curious if a variable assignment can have an exit status not zero, that
would normally continue. I came up with these, but they cause execution to stop
even without `set -e`:

```
wh=$$(
xr=${}
readonly zu=2; zu=3
```

Comment: Callling a program that fails; eg `x=$(false)`

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks - I found this too http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01